# Should I create one big pivot or multiple small pivots in a great many to many connection?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-relations

I have the following tables: `Users`, `Regions` and `Teams`. Every tables are in many-to-many connection with eachother and I need every connection from every direction. In other words:

- `Users` can be in multiple `Regions` and `Teams`.
- `Regions` can have multiple `Users` and `Teams`.
- `Teams` can be in multiple `Regions` and have multiple `Users`.

How should I implement the pivot table between them?

### Create multiple small pivot tables between each tables

[image: Multiple small pivot tables between each tables]

### Create one big pivot table between all table

[image: One big pivot table between all table]

Which one should I use? Is there actually a perfect solution or are there pros and contras?
Would the answer different if I have to connect 4 or more tables the same way, where there would be 6 - or (n(n-1))/2 for any n - pivot table?

Comment: Does the user belong to a region independent of a team? Or does a user belong to a specific region because that person's team is in that specific region?

Comment: @AgRizzo No, regions and teams ar two separate things. A user can be part of a region but also part of a team that is in a totally different region. For example user lives in Hungary but works in an american team remotely.

Comment: Go with the first solution - the second is a relationship between the user, Hungary, and American team. Then you would need to create another entry for every variation of team and region for that user.

Comment: @AgRizzo Yes, but if I need to add a fourth table, there will be a lot of pivot tables.

Comment: A lot of tables is not necessarily a bad thing, it is expected when you are storing normalised data. As an aside, the tables you are describing are [junction tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), not [pivot tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table). You should have as many junction tables as required, by the sounds of it you have three seperate relationships, Teams >> Users, Users >> Regions, Regions >> Teams. All three are independant so each relationship should have its own junction table, so use your first method.

Comment: The junction tables represent the relationship, which you have not described as being 3 way, but a standard M:N. Conceptually, think about how much redundant data you would have in your 2nd example. Also, here is a relevant article on the [4th Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form)

Answer (score 1):

In certain cases depending on many factors in your business logic, use cases, defined by the exact roles of the entities, etc. you might find the second option useful, but I would definitely go for the first one. In professional database design, every many-to-many relation is normalised using a join table (not pivot). So you would have for e.g. `User`, `Region` and `User_Region` and so on for each many-to-many relation.

I personally find it very efficient to 1) have a composite primary key consisting of both columns in each join table and 2) let the primary key of the parent tables be a foreign key referencing the join table.

A simple example of the above for one relation on MySQL command line:

```
mysql> 
mysql> create table a (id int not null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>  
mysql> alter table a add primary key (id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> create table b (id int not null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> alter table b add primary key (id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> create table a_b (a_id int not null, b_id int not null);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> alter table a_b add primary key (a_id, b_id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> alter table a_b add foreign key a_id_fk (a_id) references a (id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> alter table a_b add foreign key b_id_fk (b_id) references b (id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```